# Как добавить несколько экземпляров компонент Vue при нажатии кнопки. через метод

Tags: vue.js, компоненты

Проект на Ларавель, часть страницы рендерится через Vue. В родительском компоненте выводится список с кнопками через АПИ, при нажатии на кнопку вызывается метод, который подключает другой компонент и он меняет DOM.

```
    <template>
<div>
    <h2>My Projects</h2>
    <ul id="list" style="list-style: none; padding-left: 0px">
        <li v-for="elementList in list" :id="'li' + elementList.id" class="mt-2">
            <a :href="'/projects/id_' + elementList.id" >{{ elementList.name }}</a>
            <button @click="editElementList(elementList)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i></button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
    <script>

import Vue from 'vue'
import editList from './components/EditElementList';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            list: [],
        }

    },
    components: {
        editList
    },
    mounted() {
       this.getList();
    },
    methods: {
        getList() {
            axios
                .get('/api/project/project-list')
                .then(response => {
                    this.list = response.data
                    console.log(response.data)
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                    this.errored = true;
                })
                .finally(() => this.loading = false)
        },
        editElementList(elementList) {
            let li = document.querySelector('#li' + elementList.id);
            let ComponentClass = Vue.extend(editList)
            let instance = new ComponentClass({
                propsData: {elementList},
            })
            instance.$mount() // pass nothing
            li.innerHTML = '';
            li.appendChild(instance.$el)
        },
        saveEditElementList(elementList) {
            console.log(elementList.name);
        }
    }
}
```

На удивление код работает, и подключаемый компонент рендерится и заменяет содержимое в теге li. Но не работает this.emit() в подключаемом компоненте. Не работает он потому что у него свойство this.$parent не определено.

```
    <template>
<div>
    <form @submit.prevent="saveEditElementList">
            <input type="hidden" v-model="elementList.id">
            <input type="text"  v-model="elementList.name">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right mt-1">save</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
    <script>
export default {
    props: ['elementList'],
    data() {
        return{}
    },
    methods: {
        saveEditElementList: function () {
            // генерируем событие 'saveEditElementList' и передаём name и id элемента
            this.$emit('saveEditElementList', this.elementList);

        }
    }
}
```

Кто знает как можно динамически подключить компонент и что бы в дочернем компоненте работал метод this.$emit()

Comment: а зачем вам vue, если вы компонент рендерите на сервере? еще и селекторами выцепляете элемент на странице и используете innerHTML, append. Смысл вам vue тогда использовать. У вас два варианта - не изобретать велосипед и отказаться от vue или создать компоненты, а сервака получать только данные для них и использовать фреймворк как он задумывался

Comment: И лучше именно второе, где клиент у Вас отдельно, а сервер как API только данные отдает.